# regex matching characters AROUND a character, AND operator in regex?

Tags: regex

I'm not that impressive when it comes to regex...

I'm trying to match essentially all the characters in a word except for the second character.

I want to match the '&' and the 'uml' but not the second character in the string.

example strings:

> &auml &zuml &ouml &euml

I have come up with the following 2 regular expressions.

this one matches "uml" except for the first character(&):

`(?=.)uml` --> https://regex101.com/r/yrhzSU/1

this matches the first character except for the last 3 (uml)

`&(?=.)` --> https://regex101.com/r/LgRtd3/1

You'd think combining these would be easy but I'm struggling to find any kind of AND operator. I can use an OR (|) operator but that would also match strings that arent strictly starting with '&' and ending with 'uml'.

```
&(?=.)uml
```

Link to regex with OR combination: https://regex101.com/r/MuhxM9/1

Comment: What you could do is use 2 capture groups instead `(&)[aeoz](uml)` https://regex101.com/r/tIXxHk/1

Comment: Hi @Thefourthbird, I believe that expression would also match with the second character. I'm trying to match the first character (&) and characters 3,4 and 5. You may have put me in the right direction though, i'll try to work with that. Thank you!

Comment: It does match the second character, but you can not really skip a character while matching like that. This way you have 2 capture groups.

Comment: What will you be doing with the captured data? If you're just outputting it and the `&` is guaranteed then prefix the `&` manually upon output. If the `&` can be something else like `$` then you need to use capture groups and concatenate group 1 to group 2 per @Thefourthbird's example.

Comment: Hi @MonkeyZeus, I'm aiming to use a -replace to remove these matched characters 

I want to turn "&aum" into "a" for example

Comment: Then you can match `&([aeoz])uml\b` and replace with group 1 See https://regex101.com/r/DczyWC/1

Comment: @KissyKissyBangBang That's dead simple; here you go https://regex101.com/r/gg5gSq/1

Comment: Looks like you are converting HTML/XML entities to their literal representation. Right? Are you using Python?

Comment: If you are converting those values, and you are using Python, I have a comprehensive function that does the cleanup, just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a combination of positive lookaheads and lookbehinds, I believe you can achieve that

```
&(?=.uml)|(?<=&.)uml
```

[Regexr](https://regexr.com/5topp)

Explanation:

- `&(?=.uml)` matches a `&` followed by `.uml` but does not include `.uml` in the match
- `(?<=&.)uml` matches a `&.` (which is not included in the match because it is in a lookbehind) followed by `uml`.

Hopefully, this helps

Edit: I removed the unnecessary capturing groups that [@The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird) pointed out

Comment: Note that you don't need the capture groups and you might make the pattern a bit more specific `&(?=[aeoz]uml\b)|(?<=&[aeoz])uml\b`

Answer (score 1):

About the patterns that you tried:

- Using `(?=.)uml` will always match `uml` as the positive lookahead asserts that what is directly to the right is any char (Which is `u` so you can omit the lookahead)
- Using `&(?=.)` matches the ampersand, and asserts that there is any char directly to the right
- Using `&(?=.)uml` will not match anything as the lookahead is an assertion which is non consuming and asserts (not matches) the char before uml)

If you want to do a replacement, turninng `&aum` into `a` instead of using lookarounds,you can match the ampersand, capture 1 of `a` `e` `o` or `z` using a character class in  group 1 and match the following amp

In the replacement use capture group 1 keeping what you have captured.

```
&([aeoz])uml\b
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DczyWC/1)